# Entity Framework don't take data from table which is related

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hello I have problem with EntityFramework. I have relation one to many.

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; } = false;

    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

and secound class:

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

How we can see I set relations between these tables.
Unfortunatelly when I do simple select

```
_context.Question.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddDate).Take(10)
```

Answers object is always null.
I checked Keys in MSSQL. Question table don't have any FK to Answers, but Answers have FK to Question.

Can anybody explain for me what I am doing wrong? Why FK is not created?
I was trying virtual type but it is not helping.

Comment: Just a guess: usually you have to make properties virtual to enable lazy loading, or you have to use eager loading (include the required,related objects when loading them), 
e.g in your case (with eager loading:)
`_context.Question.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddDate).Include(x=> x.Answers ).Take(10)`

Comment: FK is exactly where it should be - at the `many` side. So the relationship is ok, but it is not populated automatically. Insert `.Include(x => x.Answers)` in your query. Reference: [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any FK in the `Question` table, because the shadow property for the FK is created only on the 'many' side of the relationship in the Answer object.

You, basically, have [two options](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html):

1. Explicitly load the Answers:

   ```
   var questions = _context.Question.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddDate).Take(10);
   _contest.Answer.Where(x => questions.Select(q => q.Id)
                              .Contains(EF.Property<int>(x, "QuestionId"))).Load();
   ```

After this a bit convoluted statement all Answers will be populated with the appropriate objects. Note the use of the autocreated shadow property for FK. More on the naming conventions [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/shadow-properties.html).

2. Far more easily would be to eagerly load the collections:

   ```
   _context.Question.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddDate).Take(10).Include(x => x.Answers);
   ```

This is much more efficient and just plain readable and concise code, in my opinion.

Also, it's worth noting that [**EF Core does not support lazy loading**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797) as of this moment.