# EntityFramework - get list of Products, each with List of Images

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have a table of Products in a database, and a table of ProductImages, with corresponding models like so:

```
public class Product {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<ProductImage> Images {get;set;}
}

public class ProductImage {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Url {get;set;}}
}
```

Obviously, I can get a list of products like so:

```
var query = from p in db.Product select p;
```

How could I get a list of products such that each ProductModel's Images property has been populated with the images with matching ProductId?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework don't take data from table which is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704086/entity-framework-dont-take-data-from-table-which-is-related)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx), this ensures that the related entities are also retrieved.

```
var query = from p in db.Product.Include(x => x.Images) select p;
```

This assumes that you mapped the relationship between `Product` and `ProductImage` and as there is no mention of it not being mapped I believe this assumption is valid.

Comment: I created the tables manually - not sure how to create the mapping.

Comment: @user888734 - you can add mapping one of two ways. 1. Use annotations, there are some good examples of that in other answers to your question. 2. Use a [fluent mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just your ORM models, you would also need to do some configuration. In your migration configuration file, you can do this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
.HasMany<ProductImage>(pI => pI.Product)
```

Taken from [Source](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

You could also write an `.Include(p => p.ProductImages)` where ever you are fetching your data. I use a repository design pattern, so I put that in my repository, but where ever you're calling to get the data you can `.Include(p => p.ProductImages)`

**EDIT** 
just noticed you're missing something in your ProductImages model

```
public virtual Product Product {get; set;}

[ForeignKey("Product")]
public int ProductId {get;set;}
```

Comment: On your last edit, it is not required to have 2 way mappings of relationships. One way mapping is usually acceptable and sometimes even recommended. It comes down to how the model is used.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways of doing this is by using Entity Framework data annotations which allows you to configure one-to-many relation between two entities and populate navigation properties:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ProductImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```